# How to convert MYSQL Timestamp to CST time with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql

If someone could help me with this I´d appreciate it!
I need to convert MYSQL Timestamp 2022-09-14T05:08:32.000Z to my local time (Central Standard Time) and then be able to pass that result to EJS. I am passing the data to my EJS view with this route, but not sure how to convert this timestamp before passing it to EJS.

This screenshot shows the 'rows' values which are being passed to EJS.

[image: MYSQL Timestamp]

```
rutas.get('/historial', loggedIn, async (req, res, next) => {
    await pool.query('SELECT * FROM historial WHERE id = ? AND  calidaddeltrade = ? OR calidaddeltrade = ?', [req.user.id, 'Excelente', 'Buena'], function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) { throw err };
        res.render('./historial', { rows: rows});
        console.log(rows);

    })
});
```

Does anyone know how could I do this with Javascript? Thanks!!

Comment: What is your expected output for the given `tiempo` value?

Comment: I just need to get the Day-Month / Hour-Minutes, so with that example of the screenshot I would expect Sept-14  6:08 PM

Comment: I found a way to do it, in case this helps someone, in EJS I used momentjs to convert it to UTC which gave me the local time.

<%= moment.utc(data.tiempo).format('MMM-DD HH:mm') %>

Comment: You should post that as an answer. You can accept your own answer after a waiting period.